# Loading images/videos on top of webpage's content

Tags: javascript

I have seen several websites where an image shows up on top of everything else. What is this script/library called that helps you accomplish this?

Comment: Do you have an example of the websites? There are many techniques to creating overlays and dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commonly called a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29).

Here's [a jQuery plugin to do it](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/).